# How to download python from command-line?

Tags: python, linux, command-line, download

I'm on windows, but I'm using a putty shell to connect to a linux machine, and want to install python 2.7. Can't figure out how to do it. How can I download python from command line?

Comment: Do you have admin rights on the linux machine? And have you checked if it's already there - many Linux distributions have Python there by default.

Answer (score 83, accepted):

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.11/Python-2.7.11.tgz
tar -xzf Python-2.7.11.tgz  
cd Python-2.7.11
```

Now read the `README` file to figure out how to install, or do the following with no guarantees from me that it will be exactly what you need.

```
./configure  
make  
sudo make install
```

For Python 3.5 use the following download address:
http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.5.1/Python-3.5.1.tgz

For other versions and the most up to date download links:
http://www.python.org/getit/

Comment: Also add the path of new python in 'PATH' environment variable. 
Eg. if new python is in /root/python-2.7.4 then run 
"export PATH = $PATH:/root/python-2.7.4" to detech new python verison

Comment: Use `make altinstall` if you don't want to replace the system defaults.

Comment: wget  --no-check-certificate http://www.python.org/ftp/python/2.7.6/Python-2.7.6.tgz works for me and rest as Andrew Clark said

Answer (score 4):

`apt-get install python2.7` will work on debian-like linuxes. The [python website](http://www.python.org/download/releases/2.7/) describes a whole bunch of other ways to get Python.

Comment: I tried that. I get apt-get: command not found error

Comment: What Linux distribution are you running?

Comment: If you were to tell us which version of Linux you are using it would help. There are many flavours and they differ significantly in package management.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are getting into a linux machine you can use the package manager of that linux distro.

If you are using Ubuntu just use apt-get search python, check the list and do apt-get install python2.7 (not sure if python2.7 or python-2.7, check the list)

You could use yum in fedora and do the same.

if you want to install it on your windows machine i dont know any package manager, i would download the wget for windows, donwload the package from python.org and install it