# Upgrading Python and broke yum

Tags: python

I was trying to upgrade python.  I had to versions installed on my CentoOS machine.  I was having problems running the latest version of python and a colleague recommend uninstalling python.  He said it would remove the old version and out the new one into effect.  That did not work.  No yum doesn't work:

```
-bash: /usr/bin/yum: /usr/bin/python: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

I tried to reinstall but CentOS says its (yum) already installed.

> rpm -i yum-3.2.22-40.el5.centos.noarch.rpm error: can't create
>   transaction lock on /var/lib/rpm/__db.000

Comment: The error message you listed doesn't say it's already installed. It says it can't acquire the lock which likely means either the lock is held by another process or you're not doing it as root.

Answer (score 1):

Python is a dependency of yum, you need to reinstall the original version of Python from the CentOS installation for yum to work properly.

To do this, you either need to find a Python rpm of the correct version for your architecture/distribution or [install it from source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6630994/505154).

After doing this, if you want an upgraded Python version the easiest way is to install it from source but use `make altinstall` instead of `make install`.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to use `pyenv`. System-wide upgrade is a little bit dangerous. manage your python versions with `pyenv`. see this link https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv

Answer (score 0):

If you managed to install a new version of Python, find out where it is installed to:
`which python`

Let's say it says `/bin/python`

Then either `sudo vi /usr/bin/yum` and correct the location in the file, or create a symlink `ln -s /bin/python /usr/bin/python`.

However this is not the end of it, as some other Python things will be expected to be elsewhere and not where they are right now.

This question is probably better suited for [superuser.com](http://superuser.com).