# How to install python 2.7 through CMD

Tags: python, batch-file, scripting, cmd

How to install python through command line? Can i create a batch file and run it? I tried searching over the internet but with no help.

Comment: Is there something wrong with the options listed at https://www.python.org/download/windows ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read about downloading and installing from a Windows command prompt [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6630873/how-to-download-python-from-command-line)

Even though it does contain information on Putty shell and Linux it is n't far off from Windows install. But my honest opinion is just going to the website and downloading with the pre packaged modules. Just click Windows 64 bit and it includes everything you need. After it has been installed then of course interact and use the command prompt all you want. Unless you want to be a complete command line ninja. python.org/download/windows

Comment: To install it on windows via the command line:
`msiexec /i python-2.5.msi`